How to build a project and analyze it using clang static analyzer and get output to sarif?
I'm looking for a way to integrate Clang Static Analyzer into my build process to wrap the project build and analyze it, capturing the analysis results in SARIF for further processing and integration with other tools.
Could someone provide guidance on how to achieve this? Specifically, how can I wrap the build process to incorporate Clang Static Analyzer and then obtain the results in SARIF format?
Any examples, suggestions, or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.
I also found the scan-build tool, but as I understand it, it does not support sarif output.

I also found the scan-build tool, but as I understand it, it does not support sarif output. Did the -sarif option not work?

I looked at help, but there is no such option

Make sure you are using LLVM 18.1.5.

Oh yes, my version is 11.0.1. I think that's the problem. Thank you!
